# Is every $C_0(K,X)$ space isomorphic to $C(L,X)$, for some compact $L$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $K$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $X$ be a Banach space. Denote by $C_0(K,X)$ the Banach space of all continuous $X$-valued functions defined on $K$ that vanish at infinity, equipped with the supremum norm.

($f: K \to X$ vanishes at infinity if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a compact subset $K_\varepsilon$ of $K$ satisfying $\|f(k)\| < \varepsilon$ for all $k \in K \setminus K_\varepsilon$)

For a compact Hausdorff space $L$, denote $C_0(L,X)$ simply by $C(L,X)$.

Is it true that for every locally compact Hausdorff space $K$ and Banach space $X$ there exists a compact Hausdorff space $L$ such that the spaces $C_0(K,X)$ and $C(L,X)$ are isomorphic?

I only know this is true for the special case when $K$ is an infinite set equipped with the discrete topology (it suffices to define $L$ as the Alexandroff compactification of $K$).

Comment: We may assume $K$ is noncompact, otherwise the result is trivial.  Then $K$ is locally compact, noncompact, and Hausdorff, which means it has an Alexandroff compactification $L$.  Does this suffice to find a homeomorphism between $C_0(K,X)$ and $C(L,X)$?

Comment: I need a _linear_ homeomorphism (isomorphism) between $C_0(K,X)$ and $C(L,X)$. This works in the special case I mentioned above, and the proof is simple, but I was not able to modify it to work in the general case, too. If it helps, I can sketch the proof of that particular case and explain the trouble I was having to generalize it.